What will Electric field be when the charge on negative side of Capacitor is changed?
One of the two parallel metallic plates is uniformly charged with charge $+q$, and the other one is charged with charge $-q$, the electric field between them is $E$. When the negatively charged plate is discharged then recharged with a positive charge $4q$, the electric field between the plates becomes?
In the normal capacitor ($+Q$ on one side and $-Q$ on other side), we could use Gauss Law.
$$E=\frac{Q}{ε_0A}$$
What would $Q$ be in this case and why?

Answer given is $1.5E$.

A general formulation for an electric field coming from a plane charged with charge $q$ is (from the Gauss law) given by :
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{\text{plane +q}} = \frac{q}{2\varepsilon_0 A} \vec{n}, 
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the area of the plane, $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector to the plane (and factor 2 arises because this is the field from a single plane, and the field splits into two directions by the plane).
Thus, if we have two planes that are charged with opposite charges $\pm q$ - the field between the plates will add up (the normal vectors for the negative plate will pick up an additional minus sign - we assume $\vec{n}$ pointing from positive to negative plate) leading to the electric field inside of a standard capacitor being equal to:
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_\text{between planes +q/-q}=\frac{q}{2\varepsilon_0A}\vec{n}-\frac{q}{2\varepsilon_0A}(-\vec{n}) = \frac{q}{\varepsilon_0A}\vec{n}.
\end{equation}
Now, if we have the plates charged with charges $+4q$ and $+q$ respectively, the electric field will be given by:
\begin{align}
\vec{E}_\text{between planes +4q/+q}&=\frac{4q}{2\varepsilon_0A}\vec{n}+\frac{q}{2\varepsilon_0A}(-\vec{n}) = \frac{3q}{2\varepsilon_0A}\vec{n} = \\ 
&= 1.5 \cdot \vec{E}_\text{between planes +q/-q}.
\end{align}
Note that in this configuration the electric field outside of the capacitor doesn't vanish (since there is nonzero total charge between both plates), unlike the traditional capacitor, where the electric field is present only between the plates
